# null pointer Exception in osm2Po

Tags: osm2po

I am tring to use OSM2PO on Windows 7 but nothing works.
I have JAVA Already installed. When I launch the command 
java -jar osm2po-core-4.7.7-signed.jar prefix=at "USTHB.osm"

I get this :

[image: Error message :]

AnySolutions ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please make sure the path to the osm-file is valid
2. Make sure the osm.xml itself is valid
3. Check if the osm-file contains relation-tags. If not, download osm2po-4.8.8